# Docker: Direct subdomains to specific containers

Tags: apache, docker

I'm new to docker therefore apologies if that has already been answered, however I looked and didn't really know how to search for it so I thought I'll ask a question, and if it's already answered, at least someone that knows in docker terms how this works, can help me.

So here is what I want to do.

### Subdomain x.x.com (IP A)

- Container A
- Container B
- Container C -webserver

### Subdomain y.x.com (IP B (or it could even be A, I don't know what's best)

- Container D (same as container A but different user)
- Container E (same as container B but different user)
- Container F -webserver (same as container C but different user)

And here are my questions

1. For subdomain y.x.com should I use the same IP or a different one?
2. How can I point these subdomains to the specific containers so that if you have a container at port y.x.com:8000, you can't access the container x.x.com:8001 by simply doing y.x.com:8001?
3. How can I make sure that both webservers are accessible through the different subdomains (assuming that they both run at port 80?)

I'm not 100% sure I've understood the way networks work when using docker so any pointers, would be really helpful. Should I use link? should I use --net=bridge? Is there any simpler way to do any of that? What's the best way?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, it is important to clarify what are you trying to configure. Are you configuring an Apache server as the frontend to the two sub-domains? Are you running apache in a container? What do you have in containers A, B, D, and E? Are they providing support services to the web servers (e.g., database)?

Independently of these clarifications, the most important thing you need to understand about Docker networking is that containers, by default, receive an IP belonging to a 'virtual network' that exists only in the host in which they run. Because of that, they cannot be accessed from the "outside world" (even though they can access the outside world by using the host as a gateway).

In this case, the most straightforward way to access containers from the "outside world" is to use port mapping, in which you map a port from your physical host to a container port.

For example, let's say your host has IP `10.0.0.1`, and your container runs a web server on port `80`. In order to access this container, the first thing you need to do is to start the container and map its port `80` to some port in the physical host. This will look like:

`docker run -d -p 8000:80 <image> <command>`

where `-p` is the relevant option that you use to map ports (in this case, you are mapping port `8000` in the physical host to port `80` in the container). Therefore, to access the container web server, you will need to use the host IP with the mapped port (`10.0.0.1:8000`) - and the request will be redirected to port `80` of the container.

So, assuming you are running all containers on the same host, *you could map each subdomain to the same IP but different ports, and map each of these ports to the port 80 of containers C and F.*

Having said all of this, recent Docker versions have been adding many new ways of configuring the network, but I feel it is really important to understand the basic behaviour before moving to more complicated scenarios.

Have a look at the basic configuration instructions here:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/networkingcontainers/

Comment: Hello virsox, Thank you a lot for the reply. Up until this part, it is clear to me. The other servers run supporting services, accessible through ports only so that's fine. However what is not clear, is how can I run both webservers, that are accessible through a different subdomain? Do I simply create a new vhost configuration on the host server? Or is there a way to do it through docker already?

Comment: I'm not an Apache specialist, but I would try: 1) run Apache on container C, configured with domain `x.x.com`, port 80. 2) Run another Apache on container F, with domain `y.x.com`, port 80. 3) Configure the redirects (let's say 8080 -> ContainerC:80, 8081 -> ContainerF:80). 4) On the host server, create one VHost for each subdomain and proxy the requests to the containers (using something like `mod_proxy` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_http.html)

Comment: Or you could try to use DNS to resolve your subdomains to different servers.